# Maven tests are running well locally (OSX) but not running at all on remove CI machine

Tags: maven, ubuntu, testing, junit

I have some Maven tests suite using Junit 4.12, that running well using  'mvn test' locally on my Mac, but not running at all on remote CI machine:

```html
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ AndroidAutomationTests ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/circleci/project/AndroidAutomaticTests/src/main/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ AndroidAutomationTests ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ AndroidAutomationTests ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/circleci/project/AndroidAutomaticTests/src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ AndroidAutomationTests ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) @ AndroidAutomationTests ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.619 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-17T07:33:04Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is the POM.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <browserStack>0</browserStack>
                        <jenkins>0</jenkins>
                        <kobiton>0</kobiton>
                        <bs>null</bs>
                        <buildDirectory>${project.build.directory}</buildDirectory>
                        <appPath>k</appPath>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <groupId>GlucoMe</groupId>
    <artifactId>AndroidAutomationTests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20171018</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Both Maven versions are 3.6.0, and it's exactly the same project and branch.
Any idea?
Also, all tests name ends with "Test" and so are the tests classes.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you add some more details. Name and location of the test class would be helpful. Also details of maven configuration (pom.xml) as well as the OS of the CI system

Comment: You might be suffering from a case sensitivity issue. If your CI system is linux based and has a case sensitive file system and your Mac has a case insensitive file system. By default I believe maven will look for *Test.java if you have a file footest.java this will be found on a case insensitive file system but not on a case sensitive file system. Were as fooTest.java would be found on both.

Comment: I added my pom.xml file to the description. regarding the case-sensitive, it's not the case, they are all written with camel case (aka FooTest.java) and also the test methods.